# C# Implicitly Typed Variable re-initialize

Tags: c#

How do I re-initialize a Implicitly Typed Variable (var) in C#?

```
            var abc = new Class();
            if (a == 1)
            {
                abc = new Class1();
            }
            else if (a == 2)
            {
                abc = new Class2();
            }
            else if (a == 3)
            {
                abc = new Class3();
            }
```

Right now I have it like above and I am getting an error.

Cannot implicitly convert type 'Class1' to 'Class'

Comment: Could you explain why you want to do this? Maybe there's a better solution for your problem, but without the context it's impossible to tell.

Comment: Replace `var` with `object`, but that defeats the purpose of var.

Answer (score 7):

You can't. `var` doesn't work like that. `var` means "look, I'm too lazy to type out the real statically typed name of this variable, can you just figure it out for me?" That's what implicit typing means.

So, on the first line, the compiler decides that `abc` is typed as a reference to `Class`. Then, you later try to assign a reference to `Class1` to `abc`. Of course that's impossible unless there's a conversion from `Class1` to `Class`.

To stress, your code is as if you'd written

```
Class abc = new Class();
if (a == 1) {
    abc = new Class1();
}
else if (a == 2) {
    abc = new Class2();
}
else if (a == 3) {
    abc = new Class3();
}
```

In fact, it's semantically identical. But now your error is obvious. You're trying to assign a reference to `Class1` to `abc` but `abc` can't accept that unless there's an implicit conversion from `Class1` to `Class`.

Answer (score 7):

Implicit typing with *var* is still static typing

```
var abc = new Class();
```

is exactly equivalent to

```
Class abc = new Class();
```

Unless Class1, Class2 and Class3 extend Class, you can't assign them to abc.

Comment: Or there's an implicit conversion from `Class1` etc. to `Class`.

Comment: @Jason Good point, my wording is somewhat imprecise. In the case of a conversion it's still a Class (or possibly derivative) being created by the conversion and stored in abc.

Answer (score 3):

You can't, in that scenario you can only do that if Class1/2/3 explicitly inherit from Class.

Answer (score 2):

You don't.  Implicit initialization is determined by the compiler at the point of assignment, thus your first line:

```
var abc = new Class();
```

Is equivalent to:

```
Class abc = new Class();
```

So once it's determined to be of type `Class` it can't be changed any more than the explicit declaration can.

Perhaps you were wanting to do `dynamic` typing instead?

Answer (score 2):

You Can't do what you ask but you can do this.

```
      object abc = new Class();
        if (a == 1)
        {
            abc = new Class1();
        }
        else if (a == 2)
        {
            abc = new Class2();
        }
        else if (a == 3)
        {
            abc = new Class3();
        }
```

While this doesn't provide a lot of value.  If all of the classes inherit from a common class or interface that does some work you need to do it may be what you are going for. So for example

```
        Animal abc  = new Animal();
        if (a == 1)
        {
            abc = new Dog();
        }
        else if (a == 2)
        {
            abc = new Cat();
        }
        else if (a == 3)
        {
            abc = new Person();
        }
        abc.sleep()
```

The sleep would then invoke the correct function for which ever type it accentual was.

Answer (score 2):

You can do this `var abc = new Class();`, beacuse `var` is a generic type and when you do this you are doing exactly `Class abc = new Class();`. The problem is when you try to do `re-initalize`. But you wrong,after when you do `abc = new Class1();`, you're not reinitializing `abc` but you're passing the [pointer](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pointer_%28computer_programming%29) of the new object of type `Class`. So the compiler say that you cannot do this convertion, beacuse the type of abc is `Class`.

But you can use `object`, as said *Mark Backett*, because the type [`object`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-ie/library/9kkx3h3c%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) is the **base class** of all classes.

Also a solution could be something like this:

```
int a = Convert.ToInt(Console.ReadLine());

var abc = new Class();

if (a == 1)
    abc = new Class1();
else if (a == 2)
    abc = new Class2();
else if (a == 3)
    abc = new Class3();

public class Class { ... }
public class Class1:Class{ ... }
public class Class2:Class1{ ... }
public class Class3:Class2{ ... }
```

Comment: +1: It reiterates what's already been said by other answers, but I like the examples here a little better. I would recommend rather than using an inheritance of the class to use the implementation of an interface to link the classes. `IMyInterface abc = new Class();` ... `public class Class : IMyInterface { ... }`.

Comment: @JoelEltherton Yeah, I like the idea, maybe in this case it could be better than use an inheritance of the class. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot do this. It's just an equivalent way of writing

```
Class abc = new Class(); 
if (a == 1) 
{ 
    abc = new Class1(); // fails or requires implicit conversion
}
```

which obviously would not work in the general case.

Answer (score 0):

An implicitly typed variable still respects polymorphism - so your inferred variable is of type `Class`:

```
Class abc = new Class();
```

Since `Class1` does not (presumably) inherit from `Class`, it's invalid to reassign. If you want to type an inferred variable to a less restrictive base type (eg., object), you can either write out the declaration (preferred) or cast the right hand side so that the compiler infers a different type:

```
object abc = new Class(); // Preferred
var abc = (object)new Class(); // Works
```

Answer (score -1):

A little late to the party but why not:

```
if (a == 1)
{
    var abc = new Class1();
}
else if (a == 2)
{
    var abc = new Class2();
}
else if (a == 3)
{
    var abc = new Class3();
}
else
{
    var abc = new Class();
}
```

Comment: Because the code that you've posted is useless; you can never access the variables.  Presumably the variable is used following the `if/else` statement in the OP's example.